# Is it OK to connect stranded wires with different strand counts?

Tags: wire

I need to replace a damaged wire. The wire is UL1430 22AWG stranded with 17 strands. See [here](http://www.thaiwonderful.com/product/pro_detail.php?cid=21&cid_pr=21&pid=13&cname=HOOK&show=0). I can find something very close, but it's not quite the same. It is UL1430 22AWG with 19 strands, instead of 17 strands. Listed [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/10ft-of-1430-22-19-4-Yellow-Hook-Up-Wire-UL-1430-22-AWG-19-Strands-300V-Ti/143653466007?hash=item217269ef97:g:DlQAAOSwxt5fB7gH).

Is that replacement wire OK or does the strand count matter that much?

I also need to replace a UL1010 18AWG stranded wire with 16 strands. See [here](https://www.wontex.com/products_3_b.php?gid=24). But I'm having trouble finding anything close. Is there an acceptable substitute that is widely available in the US?

The wire is for internal wiring of a ceiling fan on my screened-in porch. The wire will go from the fan housing, up the downrod, to the canopy.

Comment: They're electrically equivalent.  The differences are mechanical -- so if it's not a mechanically challenging environment, then yes, you can probably just replace them.  If it *is* mechanically challenging (high temperature, lots of vibration, continual flexing, strain on the wire, etc.) then the wire selection becomes critical, and there's not nearly enough information in your question to help.

Comment: i edited the post for additional details about the environment - to what extent does that constitute a mechanically challenging environment? If the replacement has more strands than the original, would that mean it is better capable of withstanding the mechanical forces?

Comment: For a ceiling fan, any wire that fits should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the replacement has the same or better specs (current, isolation, and/or whatever is relevant to your application), I wouldn't worry about strand counts; I know I never have, except when dealing with very high frequencies. Flexibility of the wire may be an issue, though.

Comment: 17 to 19 is a tiny change, though. I agree that if the OP wanted to go to/from solid then that's definitely a question that takes a lot of other stuff into account, but if the original wire was so close to tolerances that it mattered in that much detail then it was a bad choice in the first place (in a domestic setting, we're not talking about a fighter jet).

Answer (score 1):

In general, more cores gives more flexibility and longer life in a flexing application. If your porch doesn't move in the wind then a solid core (single strand) of 22 AWG would do the job.

[image]

*Figure 1. An image search for flexible cable will give images such as those above. Note the high number of fine strands.*